# How to work with code examples in Apple's Keynote?

Tags: iwork-keynote

I'm creating a presentation in Keynote on the Mac. It is intended for an audience of Java developers, and has some slides that contain blocks of Java code. Even with a monospaced font, I find the TextBox feature to be difficult in terms of formatting.

[Crazy Bob has an article](http://www.java.net/blog/2004/03/18/code-examples-keynote) on how he handled it in 2004 (he creates PDFs from the code samples and then includes those). However, I would like to know if there have been any changes since then.

How do you work with code examples (Java, C#, Javascript, whatever) in Keynote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one of two ways:

- Short examples

  I just set the style once the way I like it, and then copy & paste the formatting everywhere it's needed.
- Long examples

  I'll use a link that kicks out to a web page that contains my code, and then I use CSS to style it just the way I want it. Also, this way I can do things like have highlighting when I hover over particular lines of code, or have a link that runs web-based examples.

  When I'm done, I just bounce back to Keynote.